# How can I search within the keymap of vim

Tags: vim

`:map` command on vim displays the list of current mappings. The problem is that the list is rather long and I don't see a way to search within it.

Is there a way to load this map into a regular vim buffer? some other way to search?

(I know I can do `:map foo` to get all mappings starting with foo, but this is not enough)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `:redir` to redirect the output of the `:map` command to a register, then paste that register into a new buffer. For example:

```
:set nomore
:redir @a
:map foo
:redir END
:set more
:new
:put a
```

The `:set nomore` and `:set more` commands turn off and back on paging so that you don't have to hit the space bar to see each page of command output while you're capturing it in the register. See

```
:help :redir
```